# Dynamically populate Dropdownlist and get the value of code behind file in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have a .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DropdownList.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test_WSMS_TV.DropdownList" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // alert('akash');
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //var arr = ["val1", "val2", "val3"];
            //alert('akash');
          //  $("#DropDownList1").prepend('<option value="akash">akash</option>');
            $("#DropDownList1").append(new Option('option1', 'option1'));
        });

    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

and code behind file is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var selectedOption = Request["DropDownList1"];
           // DropDownList1.SelectedValue
            Response.Write(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        }
```

when i click button the selected the server control value ("A") is showing but
the dynamically added value does not showing in `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`

property. How can get the dynamically added value in .cs file.

Comment: hmm...dropdownlist is a service side control and you are trying to add the value using client side script?

Comment: @user1490835 and want to get the value of .cs file by button postback

Comment: It won't work as the server side does not have any idea you have added `option`s to the dropdownlist. What you can do is a slight hack: 1. Put a hidden field 2. Before posting back on the click of your `Button1`, set the hidden field 3. Read the hidden field value in the button's click handler.